# vs code c/c++ compiling issues

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

hi there iam a begginer in programing field and i have faced a proplem in setting my coding environment in visual studio code[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUkG5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE6Rr.png) so basically that what happens when i run my "hello" program
the gcc and g++ compilers and gdb are instaled and i added the path in edit variable window i dont know how to solve this proplem anyone with field experience help me please

i tried to look for the launch.json and specify what is the proplem but that made it more complicate for me

Comment: What tutorial are you following?

Comment: Abdelhak Seghiour, please post code here, as text.

Comment: Please post text as text, not as pictures of text directly into your question. How does your `tasks.json` look like? What is the name of output file?

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file and write file extension as well. For c language, extension is .c , rename giorno to giorno.c and it will probably run.

Comment: i did what you told me but it doesnt seem to work sadly same issue with launch.json